# Ruby on Rails - db:create:all error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When I am trying to create a new rails app with a postgres db I cannot complete the rake command.

This is what I have done.

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~$ sudo -u postgres psql postgres
[sudo] password for sayth: 
psql (9.2.4)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# create role sayth login createdb;
ERROR:  role "sayth" already exists

postgres=# DROP user sayth;
DROP ROLE
postgres=# create role sayth login createdb;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
postgres-# \q
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~$
```

I have created my rails app with

```
rails new testapp2 -d postgres
```

realised after watching Railscast why it didn't work http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

So I edited the config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: testapp2_development
  pool: 5
  username: sayth
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: testapp2_test
  pool: 5
  username: sayth
  password:
```

But still rake wont create my database.

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~/testapp2$ rake db:create:all
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "testapp2"
...
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "database"=>"testapp2_production", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"testapp2", "password"=>nil}
```

Seems I have read a lot and tried anything I have found but unsure what to do.

This command fails as well.

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~/testapp2/config$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: do you have password for postgres, if yes then specify it, and specify port also that is default to 5432

Comment: @SachinSingh   I don't have a password where do I specify the port?

Comment: in database.yml, just like other attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the error is only in creating production database, here you have
>   specified wrong user, 'testapp2' instead of 'sayth'